# Calculate, Copy and Paste to a given value in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, copy, paste

I am fairly new to VBA. I am trying to automate iterations based on the no. of iterations specified in cell "E2". I want excel to Autofill down column A from cell "A4" to the value of cell "E2" e.g if E2 = 100, Excel will autofill series 1,2,3...down to 100.

I then want excel to continuosly calculate the value of cell "B2" then copy and paste each result down column B, starting at "B4" and stops at the value of iterations "E2"

I have the following code for the "Autofill"

```
 Sub Monte3()
       Dim srcRange As Range
       Dim destRange As Range
       Range("A5:A1000000").ClearContents
       Set srcRange = ActiveSheet.Range("A4")
       Set destRange = ActiveSheet.Range("A4:A103")
       srcRange.AutoFill destRange, xlFillSeries

  End Sub
```

I have recorded the following Macro for copy paste

```
   Sub Macro10()

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Calculate
Range("B2").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("B4").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Calculate
Range("B2").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("B5").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Calculate
Range("B2").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("B6").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Calculate
Range("B2").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("B7").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
```

What's the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A nice `For Each Next Loop` should work. See the code below. I took some guesses on some of the range references based on what you wrote above, but you should be able to modify it easily to suit your needs.

```
Sub Monte3()

Dim srcRange As Range, cel As Range
Dim wks As Worksheet

Set wks = Sheets("Sheet1") 'replace Sheet1 with your sheet name

With wks

    .Range("B5:B1000000").ClearContents
    Set srcRange = .Range("B4:B" & .Range("E2").Value + 4) 'will plug the number in from E2 as the row and adds 4 since you are starting at row 4

    For Each cel In srcRange

        With .Range("B2")
            .Calculate
            .Copy
        End With

        cel.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    Next

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Scott. Works great